Why does Producer care about partitions?
Kafka already automatically manages partitions between consumers in a consumer group. It ties partitions and consumers one-to-one, there is one partition for each consumer. Meanwhile, one has to explicitly specify the number of partitions (or the default will be used) when creating a topic.
Why does the Producer needs to care about partitions?
In my understanding, the producer needs to write messages to a topic (as opposed to a partition inside a topic), and the message will be replicated to all partitions, or some partitions, or whatever Kafka decides to ensure all consumers who need to receive that message receive it.
Making the producer manually specify to which partition inside the target topic its messages will go defeats much of the purpose of partitions, in my understanding. As though the responsibility of load balancing incoming messages is the producers' responsibility, while it should be Kafka's.
My current use case is one producer who needs to write messages exactly-once (using transactional.id) to a topic, and God knows how many consumers, all of which need to receive all messages in the topic, but each only cares about a specific subset of the messages, around 1-2% of them.


producer needs to write messages to a topic (as opposed to a partition inside a topic)... message will be replicated to all partitions, or some partitions

This is incorrect. Messages are sent to one partition. Then replicated to topic replicas for the same partition.
The Partitioner interface within the Producer API decides the partition, if a value is not specified. If you use record keys, then a hash of that is computed for the partition such that all comparable keys are ordered within the same partition. If the key is null, then partitions are round-robined.

God knows how many consumers, all of which need to receive all messages in the topic, but each only cares about a specific subset of the messages, around 1-2% of them.

You can only have as many consumers in a group as partitions. All consumers in a group will receive all messages, but if you only need a subset, you'll have to write that filtering logic in the consumer. You can explicitly assign consumers to partitions as well, if required.

Thank you for the extra info. The 1-2% filtering is of course in the consumer code, producer doesn't know anything about that. I'm not using java, I'm using golang (segment's unofficial kafka library, there is no official one). From what I understand, producer can specify which partition to send the message to, but this contradicts with kafka docs, where it is stated that kafka will load balance messages between partitions when a consumer group is being used. Can you please clarify how the full mechanism works when using consumer groups? Thanks

Kafka does not do "load" balancing. The GroupCoordinator assigns partitions across consumer instances. That could mean there might be 1000 messages in one partition, but zero in another (this would have been done by the producer code). Therefore, load of one consumer instance would be higher than another, and the broker would have no understanding of that. Similarly, the producer simply hashes a message key, or computes one in-sequence, it does not chose a broker/partition with less load when receiving a message.

I see. I think my root misconception is trying to view partition reading and writing as a single algorithm. How a producer balances writes between partitions and how reads from partitions are balanced among members of a consumer group are totally different algorithms that can or can not complement each other. This is furthered by the fact that reader offsets are entirely the readers' problem, the producer does not interact with reading in any way. Is that a correct understanding of the entire system? @OneCricketeer

Correct, writes and reads are separate, although both clients can assign specific partitions to use, this is not a common use-case
